# Rod's Kinetic Energy in the pendulum problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, kinematics, moment-of-inertia

On the MIT OCW for engineer dynamics the cart pendulum problem is solved by using the Lagrange Method [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-003sc-engineering-dynamics-fall-2011/lagrange-equations/). This is a 2D problem, so rotation only occurs on the Z axis. While obtaining the rotational Kinetic Energy that is defined as:

$V_{r} = \frac{1}{2}I_{zz}\dot{\theta}^{2}$

Where $I_{zz}$ is the zz element of the inertia matrix/tensor and $\dot{\theta}$ is the angular velocity.

The only doubt I have is related to which Inertia Matrix (of the rod) must be used for this problem, this is solved on the MIT2_003SCF11_rec8notes1.pdf from previous link by defining the rod's moment of inertia as:

$^{G}I_{zz}=\frac{1}{12}m_{2}L^{2}$

Instead of:

$^{A}I_{zz}=\frac{1}{3}m_{2}L^{2}$

Where $m_{2}$ is the mass of the rod

For calculating the kinetic energy of the rod due to rotation why we need to use $^{G}I_{zz}$ instead of $^{A}I_{zz}$?? the rod is rotating around the fixed point A, it is not rotating around its own center of mass?? rigth?

Note: the course professor gives an explanation in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QVENB3aEvY&list=PLUl4u3cNGP62esZEwffjMAsEMW_YArxYC&index=23) at 10:07 but it is still no clear for me. Look at the last term of T equation from the video if you can:

$T = \frac{1}{2}m_{1}V_{A/o}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}m_{2}(V_{G/o}V_{G/o}) +\frac{1}{2}\omega ^{G}H$

[image: Pendulum problem with cart and rod]

Answer (score 0):

In a [previous answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409296/plane-rotation-of-a-bar-in-a-viscous-fluid-computation-of-the-torque/453943#453943),  I tried to show how the inertia matrix, containing the various moments of inertia of a solid body, can be derived from "first principles". In the second half of that post, I have also included the derivation of the equations of motion for a rotating bar, attached at one end. I use derivations from Newtonian equations, rather than Lagrangian interpretation, but maybe it can still explain why when a rod is rotating around one of its end, one uses the moment of inertia relative to that rod's end. Maybe this will help you get another perspective.

Answer (score -1):

Use parallel axis theorem to calculate the K.E of the rod about point A. The additional term will be 1/12*m*l^2.

Comment: This is more like a tip than a complete answer. Use the comments section for that.